# C# if statement comparing Numbers

Tags: c#, if-statement, numbers, comparison

I'm really new to programming and have to write a little programming which tests if a number is smaller or bigger than 500, 2000 and 5000. Now I wrote this but it always takes the first else statement even if the number is bigger than 5000 it says the number is smaller than 500. Anybody knows why? Appreciate every help I get. :)

Here's the code:

```
double rebe, fuenfh = 500.00, zweit = 2000.00, fuenft = 5000.00;
    //zweiPro = 2.00, fuenfPro = 5.00, zehnPro = 10.00;

Console.WriteLine("How big is the number? Wie groß war Ihr Rechnungsbetrag? ");
rebe = Console.Read();

if (rebe >= fuenfh)
{
    if (rebe >= zweit)
    {
        if (rebe >= fuenft)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("bigger or same as 5000");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Read();
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("bigger or same as 2000 but smaller than 5000 // Groesser gleich als 2000 aber kleiner als 5000");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("bigger or same as 500 but smaller than 2000 // Groesser gleich 500 aber kleiner als 2000");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Read();
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("smaller than 500 // Leider gibt es keinen Rabatt. :(");
    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: *"if a number is smaller or bigger than 500, 2000 and 5000"* - that sounds like 3 independent (not nested) `if/else`s to me.

Comment: Use the debugger to step through your code and examine the values at each step. This is trivial code and you need to learn debugging skills if you plan on writing programs.

Comment: To compare numbers you have to parse the string to an integer. double num = Double.Parse(rebe);

Comment: Also note that although it waits until you hit Enter - Console.Read only returns a single character as an integer - so if you type 5000 followed by Enter then Read will return '5' as an integer which is 53.

Comment: Indeed, today is a good day to learn how to use a debugger. Also, read your code critically: if you end **every single branch** of a conditional with the same two statements then **those two statements are not conditionally executed** and therefore **should not be under a conditional at all**.

Comment: Don't name your numbers. There is no need to create a variable `fuenfh` (short for fivehundred in German) for the value 500. As long as this value definitely does not change, just put the number in your code, otherwise use a more generic name like "threshold".

Comment: Also, when working with "real" financial stuff ("Rechnungsbetrag" is "invoice amount") use [decimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal) instead of `float` or `double`.

Comment: @jdweng That's not enough. The problems start at `Console.Read()` which reads a single character and returns it's ordinal value as an `int`. The code in your comment does not compile because `rebe` has type `double`, and contains the ordinal of a single character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it could work, converting the input to double (as hinted by mnield) but also making the code more readible in general. Note how much shorter the code gets when you invert your conditionals.

```
Console.WriteLine("How big is the number?");
double amount = Convert.ToDouble(Console.Readline());

if (amount < 500.0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("smaller than 500");
}
else if (amount < 2000.0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("bigger or same as 500 but smaller than 2000");
}
else if (amount < 5000.0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("bigger or same as 2000 but smaller than 5000");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("bigger or same as 5000");
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

change your input from `rebe = Console.Read();` to `rebe = Convert.ToDouble( Console.ReadLine());`.  I don't think you're pulling in the value that you expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
  double fuenfh = 500.00, zweit = 2000.00, fuenft = 5000.00;
            //zweiPro = 2.00, fuenfPro = 5.00, zehnPro = 10.00;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nWie groß war Ihr Rechnungsbetrag? ");
                var eingabe = double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var rebe);
                if (eingabe)
                {
                    if (rebe >= fuenft) { Console.Write($"Die eingabe ist größer oder gleich {fuenft}"); }
                    else if (rebe >= zweit) { Console.Write($"Die eingabe ist größer oder gleich {zweit} aber kleiner als {fuenfh}"); }
                    else if (rebe >= fuenfh) { Console.Write($"Die eingabe ist größer oder gleich {fuenfh} aber kleiner als {zweit}"); }
                    else { Console.Write($"Die eingabe ist kleiner als {fuenfh}"); }
                }
                else { Console.WriteLine("Bitte Zahl eingeben!"); }
            } while (true);
```

This way you'll have whole funktion in the loop!

double.TryParse - converts your input to the double type
if (eingabe) - if numbers are entered it sends you in the if blocks with your variables
do {} while (true) - endless loop to test your function without clicking debug all the time